# Leaving internship for full time position

Tags: job-offer, internship, conflict

I am currently doing a 3-month paid internship program - it started 3 weeks ago and will be conclusive in 3 months. This company does not promise to provide me with a position afterwards.

Now I've received a full-time job offer from another company.

- If it ethical to jump ship?
- What might some possible consequences be?

Comment: If you switched, could you still work for the new company for 3 months and complete the internship requirement?

Answer (score 4):

Is it a ***nice*** thing to do? **No.**

Is it a ***good*** thing to do? **Depends who you're asking.**

Make no mistake, you are screwing your boss over by quitting. However, as you yourself have said, the company you're with right now is offering no guarantees whatsoever. That job offer, on the other hand, is **a certainty**.

Here's some advice to consider when you're in one of these tricky situations:

> **Always keep your own interests in mind.**

Your current employer sure as heck will do the same, and so will every other company you will ever work for - sometimes in your detriment. Don't feel that you should have loyalty to entities which will offer you none in return (aka 99% of all companies out there)

My personal opinion is this:

> If you have been offered a full time position and you need it, then **go for it**.

The only thing I can't be certain is whether you should give 2 week's notice or not. I think it would make little difference as you've barely been there long enough to get anything done. Sticking around for another 2 weeks is probably simply going to be awkward for everyone involved.

Answer (score 1):

Think of it this way, you're leaving a temp/contract position for a full-time position. That situation is pretty much what many people in temp positions look for, unless they only want to do temp/contract work. If they brought you on knowing that you would eventually leave, they weren't prepared to make an offer to keep you on longer, and you don't particularly want to stay, then it doesn't seem like an issue.

If it's not an internship that you actually want to finish, and you're getting paid more at the full-time job, then it seems like you should simply quit the way most FT people do. Give the old place notice and tell the new place when you want to start.